# Use parameters with user defined type parameters without declaring a default parameter for that type

Tags: c++, class, oop

This is what happened (I simplified the problem to be easier to see):

```
#include<iostream>

class number_holder{
    public:
        int value;
        number_holder(int value_to_set){
            this->value=value_to_set;
        }
};

class number_holder_pair{
    public:
        number_holder first;
        number_holder second;
        number_holder_pair(number_holder first,number_holder second) 
        {
            this->first=first;
            this->second=second;
        }
};
```

I know adding `number_holder(){}` into the `number_holder` class solves the problem, but why is that needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this constructor:

```
number_holder_pair(number_holder first, number_holder second)
{  // <--
    this->first=first;
    this->second=second;
}
```

before reaching the marked line, all the members must be initialized. However, there is no default constructor for `number_holder`, and so the `first` and `second` members can't be default constructed, and the code doesn't compile.

As you've noticed, adding a default constructor:

```
number_holder() {}
```

solves this particular problem, and allows the code to compile. Note that this fix is not entirely correct, as your `value` member is still not initialized. Instead you should do:

```
int value = 0;
number_holder() = default;
```

---

However, you don't necessarily have to provide a default constructor, so long as you initialize all the `number_holder` members before reaching the definition of the `number_holder_pair` constructor:

```
number_holder_pair(number_holder first,number_holder second)
 : first(first), second(second) {}
```

This syntax is called a member-initializer-list.